# Open/Close Activity with aNavigation Drawer in a smooth way - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, lag

I use Android Studio to create a new App. In this App i used a Navigation Drawer (given as layout by Android Studio).

Example:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class NDA extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nd);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nd, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_kp) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_vp) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sp) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_iserv3) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_lmgnhs) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_addon) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_myplan) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_myplan) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

All works fine. In use it looks like:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class VPActivity extends NDA{

    Calendar kalender = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat datumsformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm ");

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private int adgenauigkeit= 25;
    private TextView planversion, vpplan;

    private Button pdf;

    String      download_file_url;
    TextView tv_loading;
    String      dest_file_path;
    int         downloadedSize       = 0, totalsize;
    float       per                  = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vp);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_update);

        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WifiAvaible();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_vp);

        //Datenspeicher initialisieren
        SharedPreferences DB = getSharedPreferences("BDB", 0);


        //Zuletzt Aktualisiert Text
      //  planversion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      //  vpplan   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        // Zuletzt Aktualisiert Text auslesen
     //   planversion.setText(DB.getString("Keytime2", ""));

        Button pdf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);

        CONNECTION();


        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(VPActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7288296463289197/3573067062");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                //.addTestDevice("B136CA205D99D1E7F5BB6EB7106BBA2C")
                .build();
        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function

            }
        });




        FileDirection();

    }

    public void show(View v){


            int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Kein Vertretungsplan verfügbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("", null);
                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                sbView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                TextView tv = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                snackbar.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kein Vertretungsplan verfügbar",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }







    public void FileDirection(){
        File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "JK-Cache"));
        try {
            if (dir.mkdir()) {
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File dir2 = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "JK-Cache/IMG"));
        try {
            if (dir2.mkdir()) {
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File dir3 = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "JK-Cache/PDF"));
        try {
            if (dir3.mkdir()) {
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void CONNECTION() {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //do your code here
                    WifiAvaible();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                        View v= findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Code Error:3", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .setAction("Action", null);
                        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                        sbView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Error:2",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } finally {
                    //also call the same runnable to call it at regular interval
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }

    public void WifiAvaible() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

            fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_update);
            return;
        }
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_nowifi);

        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            SharedPreferences DB = getSharedPreferences("BDB", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor DBEditor = DB.edit();
            DBEditor.putString("back", "back");
            DBEditor.apply();
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_kp) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, KPActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_vp) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sp) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, SPActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_iserv3) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, ISERV3Activity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_lmgnhs) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, LMGNHSActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_addon) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, AddonMarketActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, INFOActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, SETTINGActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Teilen!");
            builder.setMessage("Leider gibt es hier noch nichts zu teilen.\nMöchtest du stattdessen die App teilen ?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "LMG_VP App - Now open ALPHA [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.jk_powered.vplmg]");
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

                    //- powered by LMG_VP [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.jk_powered.lmgvp]

                    try {
                        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                        startActivity(sendIntent);
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                            View v= findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "WhatsApp wurde nicht gefunden:  LMGE: 004mpL", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .setAction("Action", null);
                            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                            sbView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            TextView tv = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            snackbar.show();
                        } else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp wurde nicht gefunden:  LMGE: 004mpL",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }



                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Nein", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_myplan) {
            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, MPActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            SharedPreferences DB = getSharedPreferences("BDB", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor DBEditor = DB.edit();
            DBEditor.putString("back", "back");

            DBEditor.apply();

            startActivity(new Intent(VPActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        }


    }


}
```

The problem there is: By launching this Activity the App lags for the first moment. I have more Activites like the second and all works very well, but it lags by launching or closing. I searched for solutions but didnt find a great solution for this problem. If you need more Information, let me know it in the comment section. Otherwise, i hope you can help me.

Comment: Use method tracing to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you explain me, where i can find it ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html

Comment: @CommonsWare i spend many time by opening an activity and by opening/closing my navigation drawer. Overall ~ 4% CPU but by opening up to ~15%. By launching Activity ~23%.

Comment: @CommonsWare AppTrace: [link](http://jk-powered.de/LoaditDown/JK/AppTrace.zip)